# Using ostream_iterator and operator << to display a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I'm trying to display a vector of pointers on objects using `ostream_iterator` and the `operator <<`. Thus, I override the `operator <<`. The problem that I always get the vector elements address. How do I make the iterator to print the actual values? Do I need to specialize it?

```
class A {
private:
    double x;
    long y;
public:

    A(long xx, double yy) :x(xx), y(yy){};
    ~A();
    void Display();
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const std::vector<T> &v) {
    using namespace std;
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<T>(os, "\n"));
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<A*> aVect;
    FillA(aVect);
    cout << accountVect;

    return 0;
}
//
output
00657990
006579D0
00657A48
```

Comment: Well one solution might be to make the function take a vector of <T*> instead of T if that works for your purposes?

Comment: no it won't works I get an error : error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'A *const ' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Fix your code so it (a) compiles, and (b) exhibits the behavior you claim it does. From what I see, it should work once you fix your errors. [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/Jzqr92). "The problem that I always get the vector elements address" - no, it prints the address stored in each element, not the address *of* each element.

Comment: Firstly, change your template specialisation so it works with a vector<T *>.  Second, you will not be able to dereference pointers using an `ostream_iterator`, because `std::copy` does not do that.  You will need to implement the loop yourself, rather than using `std::copy()` and an `ostream_iterator`.

Comment: Yeah you're right I didn't think it through, I'll think if there is a trick to do that but I think that Peter might be right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've a bit modified your code to work:

```
#include <functional>

class A {
    public:
        A(){ x = 5; y = 5;}
        A(long xx, double yy) :x(xx), y(yy){};
        ~A();

        void Display() {
            std::cout << "X: " << x << " | Y: " << y << std::endl;
        }


        double x; // made this public just not to create an accessor
        long y;
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const std::vector<T*> &v) {
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<decltype(T::x)>(os, "\n"), [](const T* t){return t->x;});

    // or use A::Display() method with std::bind
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind(&A::Display, std::placeholders::_1));

    // or with std::mem_fn
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::mem_fn(&A::Display));
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<A*> aVect = {new A, new A, new A};
    std::cout << aVect;

    return 0;
}
```

So the first problem is that you need to specialize properly:

```
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const std::vector<T*> &v) {
```

instead of

```
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const std::vector<T> &v) {
```

This is because you have array of pointers but your current specialization works for non-pointer objects of vector.

Next, I've modified your `std::copy` call because will not work ever until you provide a `operator<<` overload for your class `A`. So, I've changed it to `std::transform` to be able to output your values.

**UPD:** also, here is a way to use your `A::Display()` method with `std::for_each` algorithm with use `std::bind` or `std::mem_fn` functional objects.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, is there a way to accede the display function inside the A class

Comment: I it's implemented and I just need to call it inside the ostream_iterator like I call the x or y

Comment: @MoezRebai I just updated the answer. You may use `std::for_each` for this.

Comment: We need to include the header functional and it will works as expected, your genius man thanks  a lot

Comment: @MoezRebai Yes, I forgot to add `#include <functional>` here but it seems you got the idea :) Thank you for the good words. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

You could write an `operator<<` overload for `A*`, but it'd be slightly nicer to dereference the pointer first, like:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const std::vector<T *> &v) {
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(),
                   ostream_iterator<T>(os, "\n"),
                   [](T const *ptr) -> T const& { return *ptr; }
                  );
    return os;
}
```

and then write the usual `operator<<` overload for `A`.

---

Note - as @WhozCraig mentioned in comments, your existing code isn't printing the *vector element's address*, it's printing the vector element as you asked, and that element *is* an address. The simplest possible fix would be to just use a `vector<A>` in the first place, if you can.

However, I've assumed you need to keep the `vector<A*>` and want to print the dereferenced `A` objects.

Also, I've stuck with your original template, but it's not entirely clear whether a non-templated `operator<<(ostream&, vector<A*> const &)` would be cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) itself uses `operator<<` for the output, you can solve this easily by doing another overload:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A const* a)
{
    // Some output of `a` here
    return os;
}
```